# PDO MySQL external connection stale after being inactive for specific amount of seconds

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection, backend

Software versions:

```
PHP 8.1.5 (cli)
mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

After migrating our database to the new server and new software I noticed strange behaviour which could be shown with this simplified code snippet below:

```php
<?php
    $host = '<remote host (external IP)>';
    $db   = '<db name>';
    $user = '<user>';
    $pass = '<password>';
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT            => 5
    ];
    try {
        //executing first statement, no problem
        echo 'CREATING PDO OBJECT'.PHP_EOL;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

        echo 'PDO OBJECT CREATED, PREPARING STATEMENT'.PHP_EOL;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT *
                FROM someObject
                WHERE objectID = 1');
        echo 'STATEMENT PREPARED, EXECUTING STATEMENT'.PHP_EOL;
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'STATEMENT EXECUTED, FETCHING RESULT: ';
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        echo count($result).PHP_EOL;

        $sleep = 258;
        echo 'SLEEP: '.$sleep.PHP_EOL;
        sleep($sleep);
        echo 'WOKE UP'.PHP_EOL;

        //executing second statement after sleep, hangs
        echo 'PREPARING STATEMENT'.PHP_EOL;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT *
                FROM someObject
                WHERE objectID = 2'); //hangs here
        echo 'STATEMENT PREPARED, EXECUTING STATEMENT'.PHP_EOL;
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'STATEMENT EXECUTED, FETCHING RESULT: ';
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        echo count($result).PHP_EOL;

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
         throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }
```

This script output is:

```
CREATING PDO OBJECT
PDO OBJECT CREATED, PREPARING STATEMENT
STATEMENT PREPARED, EXECUTING STATEMENT
STATEMENT EXECUTED, FETCHING RESULT: 20
SLEEP: 258
WOKE UP
PREPARING STATEMENT
```

After this, the process becomes stale and does nothing, PREPARING STATEMENT is the last sentence I see in the output until max execution time is reached - then the process is dropped by PHP. It happens always if logic reaches 258 seconds of database inactivity.

If I reduce sleep time to 257 seconds - it always works, I see a second result, and the script finishes successfully. For me, it looks like there is some parameter that blocks connection after 257 seconds of inactivity.
On the MySQL side, I see following

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| Id   | User   | Host   | db   | Command  | Time | State | Info |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
| <id> | <user> | <host> | <db> | Sleep    | 1258 |       | NULL |
+------+-----------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

As you may see - Time is 1258 here, it never gets closed (only after it reaches MySQL wait_timeout).
MySQL timeouts below

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout                   | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout            | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout            | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout       | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout          | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout        | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout               | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout                 | 31536000 |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout            | 30       |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60       |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout          | 0        |
| mysqlx_read_timeout               | 30       |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout               | 28800    |
| mysqlx_write_timeout              | 60       |
| net_read_timeout                  | 30       |
| net_write_timeout                 | 60       |
| replica_net_timeout               | 60       |
| rpl_stop_replica_timeout          | 31536000 |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout            | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                 | 60       |
| ssl_session_cache_timeout         | 300      |
| wait_timeout                      | 28800    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You may say that the DB connection shouldn't be kept open if not needed and I agree with that, it is what I did to fix this problem. However, on the previous server, I noticed nothing like that and wondering what's happening here.
Please, don't suggest using the persistent connection, I want to find the reason, not fix consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being on the Azure side.
Since both servers were hosted there, I found that Azure Firewall considers TCP connection dead and drops it after 4 minutes of inactivity as stated here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall/firewall-faq#what-is-the-tcp-idle-timeout-for-azure-firewall

[image]

It is about any connection, not only about SQL one.
Maybe this would be useful to someone

Could be fixed by changing TCP kernel parameters default value:
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time to any value lower than 4 minutes

Comment: Cheers for the well-researched problem, and glad you found the answer. 258 seconds is longer than 4 minutes (=240 sec) though, is there are 17 second grace period or what's going on?

Comment: @MarkusAO thank you and you're right about noticing the difference in timing. It's something on the Azure firewall side, they simply don't guarantee that the connection will be open after 240 seconds, meaning it could be cut later. I found no reason for this delay on code or server side